# angular2-realtimegeolocation/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation

I have installed npm package nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation to access the geolocation. However, I encounter an error -

```
./node_modules/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/dell/Downloads/Angular-6-Templates/5th March-2019/node_modules/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library.
```

I tried to include the files in tsconfig.spec.json and tsconfig.app.json as referred from various sources but to no avail.

Changes done:

[1]
**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "index.ts",
    "../node_modules/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation/index.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "**/*.index.ts",
    "../src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

[2]

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation/**/*.spect.ts"
  ]
}
```

[3] I even removed index.ts file from the nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation but it gives index.ts "file not found" error.

Comment: It can be package issue, did you checked dependencies of package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/nemex-angular2-realtimegeolocation?activeTab=dependencies

Comment: Thanks ! solved